# How to set a checkbox as checked conditionaly

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a JSON where some fields are boolean, but unfortunatelly they values aren't 1/0 or true/false.
Instead of that they have values "Y"/"N" and i struggle with it.

I'm trying to set checked attribute basing on condition like:

```
[checked]="myobj.isdeleted == 'Y' ? true : false"
[attr.checked]="myobj.isdeleted == 'Y' ? true : false"
```

or

```
[checked]="myobj.isdeleted == 'Y' ? true : null"
[attr.checked]="myobj.isdeleted == 'Y' ? true : null"
```

but none of them works.
Any ideas how to achieve that?

Full markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="isdeleted"  [checked]="myobj.isdeleted=='T' ? true : false" id="isdeleted" [(ngModel)]="myobj.isdeleted">
```

Comment: have you tried with `[attr.checked]`? Also mind the difference between `==` and `===` in Javascript

Comment: yes I have tried, no result

Comment: Please post the full markup of the checkbox element.

Comment: done, I've pasted the full markup

Comment: You should not use `[checked]` and `[(ngModel)]` at the same time. They are competing to set the value.

Comment: Do you want to change the value of `myobj.isdeleted` when you check/uncheck the check box?

Comment: Yes of course, I want to set "Y"/"N" depending on checkbox state.

Comment: Actually I found out, that the condition is correct if I don't have [(ngModel)] property. But how can I obtain the current state of checkbox if I don't use the [(ngModel)] property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a property in the component class:

```
public get isObjectDeleted(): boolean {
    return this.myobj.isdeleted === "Y";
}
public set isObjectDeleted(value: boolean) {
    this.myobj.isdeleted = value ? "Y" : "N";
}
```

and use that property for `ngModel`, as shown in **[this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnda5x)**:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isObjectDeleted" name="isdeleted" id="isdeleted" />
```

---

If you want to pass the name of the property (e.g. `isdeleted`) as an argument, you can use `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` separately:

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="isChecked('prop1')" (ngModelChange)="setChecked('prop1', $event)" name="prop1" />
```

with the two public methods defined in the component class:

```
public isChecked(propName: string): boolean {
    return this.myobj[propName] === "Y";
}
public setChecked(propName: string, value: boolean): void {
    this.myobj[propName] = value ? "Y" : "N";
}
```

Comment: but what if I have more fields than one? You hardcoded isdeleted, is any way to pass a name of field?

Comment: This answer shows how to solve the case given in the question. For several fields, your sample code would be different, I assume. You may then need to separate `[(ngModel)]` like this: `[ngModel]="isDeleted(someName)" (ngModelChange)="setDeleted(someName, $event)"`.

Comment: shouldn't first argument of setChecked be string? :)

Comment: amazing, works perfectly i didn't even know before that is possible to split [(ngModel)] to getter and setter property, actually I found out right now that is the same concept as in for ex. c# language. thanks one more time, you saved many hours of my time :)